# Decrease integer over time during touchesBegan function

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to decrease a value over time inside of the `touchesBegan` function once it is called.I have created a function for this value (updateJumpMotion).This function works (tested).

However, since it is called only once until the touch ended it only decreases once (should increase during the entire touch, not only once).

**How can I decrease an integer over time inside of the `touchesBegan` function?**

This is my `touchesBegan` code and my function for decreasing the integer:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    // Character
    updateCharacterPosition()
    updateJumpMotion()
  }


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.02, target: self, selector: Selector("updateJumpMotion"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    if onGround && !gameOver {
        if self.initialJumpY == nil {
            self.initialJumpY = self.character.position.y
        }


        if self.character.position.y - self.initialJumpY! < 175 {
            self.character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, self.jumpVelocity))
        }

    }

    self.onGround = false

}


func updateJumpMotion() {
  if onGround {
        self.frameCounterY = 0
        self.negativeVelocity = 0
    } else {
        self.frameCounterY = self.frameCounterY + 0.15
        self.negativeVelocity = CGFloat(self.frameCounterY * self.frameCounterY)
    }
  self.jumpVelocity = 125 - self.negativeVelocity
 }
```

Comment: Loop on another thread till touchesEnded is called?

Comment: as a touch can begin only once, it is not surprising... you may need to set up an `NSTimer` which fires when the touches began and being invalidated when the touched ended.

Comment: @holex I've tried that, but without success so far. It causes a big delay in the jump mechanism.

Comment: set the repeat timer down to `0.02` which give you a chance to update the value by 50 FPS; that should be enough.

Comment: @holex See my edit. It does jump without delay, and `self.jumpVelocity` decreases over time inside of `updateJumpMotion`, but it stays at `125` inside of the `touchesBegan`

Comment: @NGAFD, I'm not sure how and when you update the UI, but try to log the `jumpVelocity` in `func updateJumpMotion()` method and you will see how the value changes; meanwhile the timer should be fired at the end of the scope logically, obviously after when you inited the environment.

Comment: @holex On every touch, jumpVelocity starts to decrease from 125 to 0. It updates within the `touchesBegan` and the jumpVelocity updates in `updateJumpMotion`.

Comment: @NGAFD, you just need to reorganise your code then, as you already know which part of your code need to be called _repeatedly_ and which will be called _once_ only.

Answer (score 0):

Start a repeating NSTimer and have that timer decrease your value each time the timer fires. If you want to stop decreasing your value when the user releases the view, put code in touchesEnded that invalidates the timer.

Comment: I've added `self.jumpTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateJumpMotion"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` to my `touchesBegan` function, but I don't know how to link it to the `jumpVelocity`?

Comment: The user is using spritekit and I assume he's making a game it's much better to use SKAction.waitForDuration as NSTimer ignores pausing of events and can cause unknown bugs when working with spritekit

Answer (score 0):

First you can create a SKAction inside your `touchesBegan` function and then use the property `SKAction.waitForduration(// some value)`. Next you write this code to ensure that it repeatsForever `self.runAction(yourAction.repeatActionForever)`.

```
//Example working code
let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(some duration)
let waitActionRun = SKAction.runBlock {
// do something that you want to do here

}
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([waitAction,waitActionRun])))
```

Comment: The `touchesBegan` function only lets everything inside of it run once. If I add the SKAction it does decrease the value, but it doesn't link to the `self.jumpVelocity` outside of the `SKAction`. 

I might be doing something wrong, though.

Comment: `touchesBegan` runs once, which triggers your action to run. Since the action is configured to run forever, it will run multiple times. Can you elaborate more on how it isn't liking to the self.jumpVelocity outside the action?  Is it not working? Show ur code

Comment: I've edited my post, but the problems start when XCode says it doesn't recognize the `repeatActionForever`. I must admit that I have not worked with SKActions yet, so I really need some help on that.